# How do I set the active state for an element which is part of an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have an `ng-reapeat` loop which shows a list of flights.  I want to set an `.active` class for the flight date originally searched for.  This `.active` class would need to go on the `<li>` element but I can't put it on every `<li>` element.

Anyone got any ideas?

Here's my html code so far:

```
    <div data-ng-if="cheapestFlights.length>0" class="u-filter-container">
        <ul class="u-filters-list">
            <li data-ng-repeat="flight in cheapestFlights" class="u-filters-list-item">
                <span data-ng-click="$parent.selectedCheapestFlight = flight" data-ng-class="{selected:$parent.selectedCheapestFlight==flight}">
                    <span class="u-filters-list-text u-dates" data-ng-bind="flight.DepartureDateString" ng-click="filterLowestFlight(flight.DepartureDateString)" ng-model="flight.DepartureDateString" ng-init="filterLowestFlight()"></span>
                    <span class="u-filters-list-text u-prices">{{flight.Price | currency : "£"}}</span>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `data-ng-class="{'active': searchDate == flight.date }"`

Answer (score 0):

Add ng-model to the input where the date is being searched and add ng-class on your "li" element when those values are equal:

```
<div class="flightDate">
    <input ng-model="flightDate" type="text">
</div>

<div data-ng-if="cheapestFlights.length>0" class="u-filter-container" ng-class="{'active': flight.DepartureDateString == flightDate}">
        <ul class="u-filters-list">
            <li data-ng-repeat="flight in cheapestFlights" class="u-filters-list-item">
                <span data-ng-click="$parent.selectedCheapestFlight = flight" data-ng-class="{selected:$parent.selectedCheapestFlight==flight}">
                    <span class="u-filters-list-text u-dates" data-ng-bind="flight.DepartureDateString" ng-click="filterLowestFlight(flight.DepartureDateString)" ng-model="flight.DepartureDateString" ng-init="filterLowestFlight()"></span>
                    <span class="u-filters-list-text u-prices">{{flight.Price | currency : "£"}}</span>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```